# How can I only build the server side by Meteor build?

Tags: meteor

After adding mobile platforms, meteor build will automatically build all the mobile platform and the backend server.

Is it possible to only build the backend server?

Comment: Excellent question. Wonder why wasn't asked/upvoted more. Most CD/CI tools will try to build on linux and `meteor build` refuses to build in other than OS X when the app has cordova iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the build feature doesn't do this.

There is a deprecated `meteor bundle` feature that still works though:

```
meteor bundle app.tar.gz
```

Builds a `app.tar.gz` bundle containing the server bundle.

Comment: I think I'll try to add the dummy url so that the build process can work successfully. Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Yes just give it parm `--server-only` to skip mobile client code

as in

```
meteor --release x.x.x  build --server https://example.com --directory /my/bundle/foobar --server-only  # replace x.x.x with your meteor release
```

I know this works because I use this technique in the process I built to rebuild my entire webapp and this is working in production just fine.